# Minimum distance between two moving objects

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I have been given a set of questions to solve and one of the questions was to find the shortest length of a vector with a variable (*t*) in it. The vector is given here - [Vector given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdBsd.png).

$$\begin{pmatrix} 8-3.671t \\ -4-0.003t \end{pmatrix}$$

t must be a real number and $t \ge 0$ as t stands for the variable time. I was wondering if there is a method to solve it. I tried inputting it into the formula of the length of a vector but I didn't seem to get any results. If this method works please let me know so I can recheck it again.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @Akshat: what have you tried? Can you write the norm of this vector? How can you compute its minimum value?

Comment: @cvanaret I'm not sure what a norm of a vector is, I have tried using the formula to find the magnitude of the vector which is |a| = √ax2 + ay2. Where ax is the vector a's x component and ay is vector a's y component.

Comment: Ok, it's the same thing. Now, working with $|a|^2$ should be easier (no square root) and its minimum value will be occur at the same value $t^*$ as the minimum value of $|a|$. Now, how can you find it?

Comment: So now the equation would be |a|^2 = (8-3671t)^2 + (-4-0.003t)^2

Comment: Well it's not an equation, simply the definition of $|a|^2$. Now, what do you want to find?

Comment: The value of t when |a| is smallest

Comment: Exactly. Do you know how to find the minimum value of a function?

Comment: I am familiar with how to find the minimum value of a quadratic when the value of a is positive in general form. It is the vertex point of the parabola and its y coordinate is the smallest value. I am pretty sure. Although I might be wrong @cvanaret

Comment: Good. Distribute the squares in your expression, rearrange and you should recognize your quadratic.

Comment: I now have the quadratic f(x)=13.47625t^2−58.712t+80. Finding this equation turning  point and the square root of its y coordinate should give me the smallest value for the distance between the two moving points am I right? @cvanaret

Comment: The minimum of the quadratic $f(t) = a t^2 + b t + c $ where $a \gt 0$ is at $t = - \dfrac{b}{2a} $